# Jennair JES9900BAS20 keeps blowing infinite switches on right front "custom control" element

Tags: switch

Original infinite switch (p/n W10185286) failed so I replaced with a new switch. Worked for a day or so then nothing. Replaced with a second switch. Worked at initial test, then neither element would work after reassembling everything and sliding range back in. Have confirmed continuity through both sections of the element. Checked wiring btw switch and elements and could not find any damaged/burned wires. No visual or audible indications of arcing, no burned smell at switch or anywhere else. Other elements work fine (they use different switches and are tapped off same incoming 110V legs). Multi-wire connections at blown switch are made with plugs so no individual wires are swapped. Switches are ~$100 each so I dont want to keep buying/blowing switches until I can eliminate the cause of them failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Congrats on including the model number - so many fail at that first hurdle! Can you tell us what an "infinite" switch is? It may be familiar to some, but not all. Also, please confirm that this is for the cook top, not the oven.

Comment: Perhaps the burner is bad, causing the switches to blow?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ecnerwal’s comment.
The element may ohm out good. 6-12 ohms or whatever the value but have a path to ground that you cannot see with a common ohm meter. In this case we would check the element hot to ground using a megger. A megger is a high voltage ohm meter I would be checking a heating element at at least 1000v. I would double check the wiring from the switch to the element.

As a megger will probably cost more than a element I would probably start by replacing the element itself if the wiring looks good.

Comment: Typo: "As a _megger_ will probably cost more than a _megger_". Not sure what you were after or I'd fix it myself...

Comment: Meant more than an element , thanks for pointing that out.